# MD046/code-block-style: Code block style [Expected: indented; Actual: fenced]

Tags: markdown, codeblocks

I am trying some documentation for my workspace but this error is bugging me more than expected.

- if i need to define my code block style then where?
- Or this is something I need to enable or update settings in my VS Code? as i am using VS Code to create this markup file.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple solution is to just leave the default setting and edit your Markdown to always use the same style of code blocks consistently throughout. After all, that is the point of a linter. To encourage consistent, well-formed Markdown.

But, of course, you may want to change the default. I'm assuming your are using the [markdownlint plugin for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint). As stated in the documentation:

> Rules can be enabled, disabled, and customized by creating a JSON file named `.markdownlint.jsonc`/`.markdownlint.json` or a YAML file named `.markdownlint.yaml`/`.markdownlint.yml` or a JavaScript file named `.markdownlint.js` in any directory of a project.

You can create one of the above files at the root of your project, and customize the behavior as you desire. As you don't state what behavior you desire, I will note that there are multiple options for [Rule MD046](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/main/doc/Rules.md#md046---code-block-style).

1. `consistent` (default): Whichever style is found first is enforced for every code block. In other words, all code block must be either indented or fenced. You can't mix them.
2. `fenced`: All code blocks must be fenced. Any indented code blocks will raise an error.
3. `indented`: All code blocks must be indented. Any fenced code blocks will raise an error.
4. `false`: Disable the rule and allow either or both styles of code blocks. Mix or match at will.

If you are using a YAML file, it might look like this:

```yaml
MD046: fenced
```

Just swap out `fenced` for the option you prefer.

Comment: Had the same error as OP as a result of trying to mix and match a (named) fenced code block followed by an indented code block. Wasn't aware that within a single Markdown document this was an issue. This answer pointed to the linter's (default) preference for a single (i.e. consistent) code block style within a document. Thank you.